# How to click event within an object?

Tags: javascript

If I do an onclick event. I'd like to send the event inside my object. But the only way I found to do this was to use a global function.

```
function HowGoodYouKnowIt(o)
{
    var html = `

      <div class='goodContainer'>
      <span>Worst</span>
      <div data-idx='1' style='background:red' onclick='goodClicked(this)' class='goodElement good0'></div>
        <div data-idx='2' onclick='goodClicked(this)' class='goodElement good1'></div>
        <div data-idx='3' onclick='goodClicked(this)' class='goodElement good2'></div>
        <div data-idx='4' onclick='goodClicked(this)' class='goodElement good3'></div>
        <div data-idx='5' onclick='goodClicked(this)' class='goodElement good4'></div>
        <div data-idx='6' onclick='goodClicked(this)' class='goodElement good5'></div>
        <div data-idx='7' onclick='goodClicked(this)' class='goodElement good6'></div>
        <div data-idx='8' onclick='goodClicked(this)' class='goodElement good7'></div>
        <div data-idx='9' onclick='goodClicked(this)' class='goodElement good8'></div>
        <div data-idx='10' onclick='goodClicked(this)' class='goodElement good9'></div>     
        <span>Best</span>
    </div>`;

    window.goodClicked = function(elem)
    {
         var container = $(elem).parent();
         var cidx = $(elem).data('idx');
         container.find('.goodElement').each(function(idx) {
                $(this).css('background','white');

                if (idx < cidx)
                $(this).css('background','red');

         });
    }

    $(o.container).html(html);
}

var bla = new HowGoodYouKnowIt({container:'#container'});
```

So I'd like `window.goodClicked = function(elem)`
to be `this.goodClicked = function()`

but how would I get the onclick event to go there?

`onclick='this.goodClicked()'` doesn't work

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/y37xmn9n/

Comment: You can't do it like that. `html` is just a string. You'll have to create the element using another way such as `document.createElement` and then set the onclick event using `element.onclick =`.

Comment: since this doesn't specifically answer your JavaScript question, i'm just going to post it here as a comment. 

if you turned this into a radio button group, you could get the same UI with HTML/CSS alone, and it could be interacted with via keyboards as well
http://codepen.io/scottohara/pen/eWzzvJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this one! It's simple and clean.

```js
function HowGoodYouKnowIt(o) {
  var html = `
 <span>Worst</span>
   <div class='goodContainer'>
   <div data-idx='1' style='background:red' onclick='goodClicked(this)' class='goodElement good0'></div>
  <div data-idx='2' class='goodElement good1'></div>
  <div data-idx='3' class='goodElement good2'></div>
  <div data-idx='4' class='goodElement good3'></div>
  <div data-idx='5' class='goodElement good4'></div>
  <div data-idx='6' class='goodElement good5'></div>
  <div data-idx='7' class='goodElement good6'></div>
  <div data-idx='8' class='goodElement good7'></div>
  <div data-idx='9' class='goodElement good8'></div>
  <div data-idx='10' class='goodElement good9'></div>  
  
 </div>
  <span>Best</span>`;

  $(o.container).html(html);
  $(o.container).find('.goodElement').on("click", function() {
    $(this).css("background", "red");
    $(this).nextAll().css("background", "white");
    $(this).prevAll().css("background", "red");
  });
  
}

var bla = new HowGoodYouKnowIt({
  container: '#container'
});
```

```css
.goodElement {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  border: black 1px solid;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.goodContainer {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'></div>
```

Comment: better to do $(o.container).find('.goodElement').on("click") ..... because there may be many HowGoodYouKnowIt objects around the page. but good stuff

Comment: note that spans should be inside the container to make them inline with boxes, but no biggie

Answer (score 0):

Define an onclick event using jQuery instead of a global function:

```js
function HowGoodYouKnowIt(o)
{
 var html = `
 
   <div class='goodContainer'>
   <span>Worst</span>
   <div data-idx='1' style='background:red' onclick='goodClicked(this)' class='goodElement good0'></div>
  <div data-idx='2' class='goodElement good1'></div>
  <div data-idx='3' class='goodElement good2'></div>
  <div data-idx='4' class='goodElement good3'></div>
  <div data-idx='5' class='goodElement good4'></div>
  <div data-idx='6' class='goodElement good5'></div>
  <div data-idx='7' class='goodElement good6'></div>
  <div data-idx='8' class='goodElement good7'></div>
  <div data-idx='9' class='goodElement good8'></div>
  <div data-idx='10' class='goodElement good9'></div>  
  <span>Best</span>
 </div>`;
 
 // how do I make this function this.goodClicked instead of window.goodClicked and get the click event to call it
 

 $(o.container).html(html);
  $('.goodContainer [data-idx]').click(function(){
   var $this = $(this),
      container = $this.parent();
   var cidx = $this.data('idx');
   container.find('.goodElement').each(function(idx) {
     $(this).css('background','white');
    if (idx < cidx)
    $(this).css('background','red');
   
   });
  
  })
}

var bla = new HowGoodYouKnowIt({container:'#container'});
```

```css
.goodElement {
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:5px;
 width:15px;
 height:20px;
 border:black 1px solid;
 background:white;
 cursor:pointer;
 
}

.goodContainer {
 white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>

</div>
```

Comment: yes but I want to see more answers / ways of doing this. thanks.